# MVC CRUD with multiple lists in view model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view model that has multiple lists that I want users to administer from a single screen.  Here is my view model:

```
    public int EmployerId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public string SecurityQuestionAnswer { get; set; }

    public List<BillData> BillingIds { get; set; }
    public List<GroupAccess> Groups { get; set; }
```

The goal is to allow CRUD operations for email address, pwd, etc.. as well as the 2 lists. When a user saves, all of the data will post to the controller, saving all of the data.
I can't find a way to do this without editing the 2 lists in another view and commiting to the database. I've looked at several grid components but they also commit the lists individually, not tying to the view model.

I want the view to allow CRUD operations for all data elements from the same screen and the updated viewmodel to be returned to the controller for saving.

For editing, [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) would work. How would I add a new record or delete an existing.

How would you do something like this without going to another view?

Comment: What does your view look like, does it contain all of the controls to edit the `BillData` and `GroupAccess`?  If so, then are you looking to be able to store changes "in the browser" for multiple individual items and then post them all at once?

Comment: The view doesn't contain anything to edit those. It's a blank view. Yes, I'm looking to store changes and post them all at once.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you want,  assuming you have controls on the page to edit those objects, they can only be bound to one item at a time.  So you would have to write some custom javascript to manage the "dirty" state of all the items in the lists.  And I'm not sure if or how you would serialize all that back to your controller.

Comment: I was considering using jqGrid, DataTables or Telerik MVC grid to modify the data and was hoping the model binders would be able to detect the changes. Just not sure how to tie each item to the collection as I iterate through the list.

Comment: You're assuming that ASP.NET MVC serializes the contents of those lists down to the browser.  I don't think it does, and even if it did, I would strongly recommend against doing that (at least without significant guard rails).  Imagine a model with 1000 `BillingIds`, all of that being serialized and deserialized; at best the performance would be atrocious.